# Calling a function defined in a TypeScript file from an HTML input onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

If I had a JavaScript **index.js** file like this:

```
function foo(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

and a **index.html** HTML file like this:

```
...
<script src="./index.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <label>bar
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="bar" onchange="foo(value);"/>
  </label>
  <label>baz
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="baz" onchange="foo(value);"/>
  </label>
...
```

this would log `bar` or `baz` as I check a radio button.

I want to call `foo(value)` which is defined in a **index.ts** TypeScript file like this:

```
let foo = (value: string): void => {
  console.log(value);
};
```

In **index.html** I change `<script src="./index.js"></script>` to `<script src="./src/index.ts"></script>`, then I use parcel to build the app, but the resulting built file is not able to call the function, logging  `referenceError: setLayer is not defined`.

I know that in theory the browser does not know anything about TypeScript and only knows JavaScript, but after compiling with parcel in my dist dir I see a bunch of `*js` files, one of which I thought might have included the compiled `foo()` function.

So the question is: how can I call a function inside a TS file from a HTML input onchange attribute like I would do with a JS file?

Last but not least: to build my app I invoke `parcel start` (or even `parcel run build`), and my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "app_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:build": "tsc -w",
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot execute functions directly from the .ts file. It is just the "source code" of the program, it must be "compiled" into JavaScript (and save as a .js file) before you can use any of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

Tools like Parcel and Webpack that bundle your js wrap all your modules in IIFEs so, after Parcel process your `index.ts` the function `foo` is not global and you can't simple access it from your html file any more. Without processing (like in this case: `<script src="./index.js"></script>`) `foo` is global.

**Solution:**

Make `foo` global.

```js
// index.ts
function foo(val: string) {
  console.log(val);
}

window.foo = foo;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-goldwasser-hthyh)

Comment: Great, it worked! Very interesting, I'd like to know more about this. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I took a FrontendMasters course about webpack, but they all do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing to `index.ts` directly from your `index.html` file, try pointing to the compiled files in `/dist` like so:

```
<script src="dist/index.js"></script>
```

As you correctly stated, TypeScript is simply a superset of JavaScript and can't not be interpreted by your browser - only after compiling it to JavaScript.

Comment: Changing the HTML like you suggested, when I try to execute `parcel start` I have a build error `my_path/dist/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my_path/dist/index.js'` (of course `my_path` is a real path). It's trying to look for a js that indeed does not exist. Even if I create it with tsc ./src/index.ts and change the HTML to `<script src="./src/index.js"></script>` I receive the error I described in my answer.